# SQL Select non intersecting elements from the super set

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How to choose the records in A that doesn't intersect with B? The records in A and B are already derived from a couple of inner joins. I tried left join, and right and not exists too, it's giving inappropriate results.

Comment: Select A minus B. Supported by Oracle. Not by mysql.

Comment: @Rene the application uses mySQL for it's entire operation, I can't do it. Is it possible to achieve it with mySQL with someother logic

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/

Comment: What do these tags mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT id FROM A_List
 MINUS
 SELECT id FROM B_List;
```

In here give your column name instead of id and remember same column name to give both A and B lists. Give your derived (with inner join) A list and B list for A_List and B_List and try this.